# Ребят, помогите с задачей на python. Не могу разобраться со списками

Tags: python, list

ЗАДАЧА:
Дан произвольный список из целых чисел.

> Получите НОВЫЙ список из элементов исходного, выполнив следующие условия:
>    если элемент кратен двум, то разделить его на 4, если не кратен, то умножить на два.

Я сначала записал код с функцией ranage:

```py
str1 = list(range(60))
str2 = []
for i in str1:
    if str1[i] % 2 == 0:
        a = str1[i] / 4
        str2.append(a)
    if str1[i] % 2 == 1:
        b = str1[i] * 2
        str2.append(b)
print(str2)
```

код работает, переписанный список выводит, но как только я заменяю 
`str1 = list(range(60)) -------> str1 =  [4, 6, 9, 53]` (то есть заменяю автозаполнение списка на ручное)
прг выдает ошибку `IndexError: list index out of range`

НО! если я заменяю синтаксис:

```py
str1 = [3, 56, 4, 88, 43, 98, 71, 33, 34, 456, 3453, 23]  # list(range(60))
str2 = []
for i in str1:
    if i % 2 == 0:
        a = i / 4
        str2.append(a)
    if i % 2 == 1:
        b = i * 2
        str2.append(b)
print(str2)
```

то прг работает правильно и все выводит
Я в конец запутался, помогите разобраться пожалуйста

Comment: Простите, а где у Вас переменная `str` которой Вы присваиваете значение таким образом `str =  [4, 6, 9, 53]` дальше в коде?

Comment: я там опечатался, str1*

Comment: `res = [x * 2 if x%2 else 1/4 for x in items]`

Answer (score 2):

```
source_list = [3, 56, 4, 88, 43, 98, 71, 33, 34, 456, 3453, 23]
new_list = [i * 2 if i % 2 else i / 4 for i in source_list]
```

Answer (score 1):

Потому что в `str1` нет элемета с индексом `53` к примеру. 
В вашем случае `for i in str1` Вы обращаетесь к `str[4], str[6], str[9], str[53]` А у Вас есть только `str[0], str[1], str[2], str[3]` Если нужны будут пояснения я дополню, но если вкратце то Вы в качестве индексов элементов пытаетесь использовать значения этих элементов. Для того, чтобы ваш код заработал (в том виде который есть), нужно изменить `for i in str1` на `for i in range(len(str1))`

Comment: Да, спасибо, я разобрался, но можете еще немного пояснить почему именно мы используем функции len и ranage в данном случае? len ведь подсчитывает количество элементов в списке?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема - выход за пределы индексов списка:

```
str1 = [4, 6, 9, 53]
for i in str1:
    print(i)
```

вывод:

```
4
6
9
53
```

т.е. str1[i] при первом проходе по циклу `for` - это str1[4], при втором - это str1[6] и т.д.

Comment: спасибо большое!